# Wahoo TICKR X .fit file reading/parsing and analysis in Python

Tags: python, monitoring, pyfits, heartrate

Not sure if I can post a question like this here so please redirect me if I'm in the wrong place.

I've bought a Wahoo TICKR X to monitor my heart rate during exercise. Also I would like to get more familiar with python so i decided I would like do do the analyses of my heart rate myself in python instead of in the wahoo app. I thought this would also give more freedom in the choice of visualization, testing etc.

I've recorded my heart rate for 5 minutes or so and exported the .fit file. However I can't even find a suitable library to read the .fit file. Can anyone recommend a library that works with .fit file from wahoo?

I'm using ubuntu, anaconda, python 3.7

```
import pyfits

# Load the FITS file into the program
hdulist = pyfits.open('/home/bradmin/Downloads/2020-03-26.fit')

# Load table data as tbdata
tbdata = hdulist[1].data



OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-a970e2cd9dee> in <module>
      2 
      3 # Load the FITS file into the program
----> 4 hdulist = pyfits.open('/home/bradmin/Downloads/2020-03-26.fit')
      5 
      6 # Load table data as tbdata

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyfits/hdu/hdulist.py in fitsopen(name, mode, memmap, save_backup, **kwargs)
    122         raise ValueError('Empty filename: %s' % repr(name))
    123 
--> 124     return HDUList.fromfile(name, mode, memmap, save_backup, **kwargs)
    125 
    126 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyfits/hdu/hdulist.py in fromfile(cls, fileobj, mode, memmap, save_backup, **kwargs)
    264 
    265         return cls._readfrom(fileobj=fileobj, mode=mode, memmap=memmap,
--> 266                              save_backup=save_backup, **kwargs)
    267 
    268     @classmethod

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyfits/hdu/hdulist.py in _readfrom(cls, fileobj, data, mode, memmap, save_backup, **kwargs)
    853             # raise and exception
    854             if mode in ('readonly', 'denywrite') and len(hdulist) == 0:
--> 855                 raise IOError('Empty or corrupt FITS file')
    856 
    857             # initialize/reset attributes to be used in "update/append" mode

OSError: Empty or corrupt FITS file
```

link to the file: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/6d054a5d52899aefcb1bcd22bda92ba120200326161849/b9831a

**EDIT**

I've tried this now but i get an error:

```
import fitdecode

src_file = "/home/bradmin/Downloads/2020-03-26.fit"

with fitdecode.FitReader(src_file) as fit:
    for frame in fit:
        # The yielded frame object is of one of the following types:
        # * fitdecode.FitHeader
        # * fitdecode.FitDefinitionMessage
        # * fitdecode.FitDataMessage
        # * fitdecode.FitCRC

        if isinstance(frame, fitdecode.FitDataMessage):
            # Here, frame is a FitDataMessage object.
            # A FitDataMessage object contains decoded values that
            # are directly usable in your script logic.
            print(frame.name)

file_id
developer_data_id
developer_data_id
developer_data_id
developer_data_id
developer_data_id
developer_data_id
developer_data_id
developer_data_id
developer_data_id
developer_data_id
developer_data_id
developer_data_id
field_description
field_description
field_description
field_description

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-e8d95d3087dc> in <module>
      2 
      3 with fitdecode.FitReader(src_file) as fit:
----> 4     for frame in fit:
      5         # The yielded frame object is of one of the following types:
      6         # * fitdecode.FitHeader

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fitdecode/reader.py in __iter__(self)
    191 
    192     def __iter__(self):
--> 193         yield from self._read_next()
    194 
    195     @property

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fitdecode/reader.py in _read_next(self)
    298                 assert self._header
    299 
--> 300                 record = self._read_record()
    301                 if not record:
    302                     break

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fitdecode/reader.py in _read_record(self)
    443                     self._add_dev_data_id(message)
    444                 elif message.mesg_type.mesg_num == profile.MESG_NUM_FIELD_DESCRIPTION:
--> 445                     self._add_dev_field_description(message)
    446 
    447         return message

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fitdecode/reader.py in _add_dev_field_description(self, message)
    780         base_type_id = message.get_field('fit_base_type_id').raw_value
    781         field_name = message.get_field('field_name').raw_value
--> 782         units = message.get_field('units').raw_value
    783 
    784         try:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fitdecode/records.py in get_field(self, field_name_or_num, idx)
    188         raise KeyError(
    189             f'field "{field_name_or_num}" (idx #{idx}) not found in ' +
--> 190             f'message "{self.name}"')
    191 
    192     def get_fields(self, field_name_or_num):

KeyError: 'field "units" (idx #0) not found in message "field_description"'
```

Comment: FITS is a data format used primarily for astronomy and other scientific data, so `pyfits` has nothing to do with this.

Answer (score 2):

The format seems to be [this FIT format](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/FIT). `pyfits` is for an entirely different format, it seems.

The article above refers to a `gpsbabel` tool, which you could use to convert the FIT file to something more interoperable and usable, e.g. GPX (an XML-based format that's easy to parse).

Or, of course, if you want a pure-Python solution, <del>you can [port the FIT format reading bits from gpsbabel](https://github.com/gpsbabel/gpsbabel/blob/master/garmin_fit.cc) to Python</del> use the [`fitdecode`](https://pypi.org/project/fitdecode/) library.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question, could you maybe share some code on how to access the data? I'm trying to read it but it gives an error (see edit question). How would i go about transforming the data to a format I can handle?

Comment: It's possible that the library can't handle your particular file for some reason, or the file is broken somehow. You'll have to debug things from there...

Comment: it is not broken, if use three consecutive apps to export the data I can get a .csv.